# Getting audio route gives empty string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I'm currently working with a piece of code to detect whether a user has plugged in/unplugged headphones with their iPhone.  The method I'm using to detect it is shown below.

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID,UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue){                            
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

    CFStringRef route; UInt32 routeSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute,&routeSize, &route);
    NSString *oldroute = (NSString*)route;
    NSLog(@"Audio Route changed to: %@",oldroute);
}
```

My issue occurs when I go to unplug the headphones.  Plugging them in works as I expect, with the Log file showing "Audio Route changed to: Headphones", however, when I unplug I get an empty string for oldroute.  I was hoping that this value would be "Speaker" as it says in the Apple documents.  Has anyone seen this before?  Am I doing something wrong in getting the string oldroute?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have not found a good answer for the exact issue that I have posted as the question.  Here is a workaround that may work for some people with a similar problem.  This solution gives you the route that was active before the change.  Ex. if you unplug your headphones you will get a string that is "Headphones" or if you put in your headphones you'll get a string that is "Speaker".

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID     inPropertyID,UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue){                            
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

    CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;
    CFStringRef oroute;
    oroute = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(routeChangeDictionary,   CFSTR(kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_OldRoute));
    NSString *oldroute = (NSString*)oroute;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: I'm going to accept my answer until a better one comes along

Answer (score 0):

I currently use the following:

```
void _propertyListener( void *                  inClientData,
                   AudioSessionPropertyID   inID,
                   UInt32                  inDataSize,
                   const void *            inData) {

if (inID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) {
    return;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kAudioRouteChanged object:nil];
});

}

- (void) _audioRouteChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    NSLog(@"audioRouteChanged");

    UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;

    OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &routeSize, &route);

    /* Known values of route:
     * "Headset"
     * "Headphone"
     * "Speaker"
     * "SpeakerAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadphonesAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadsetInOut"
     * "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
     * "Lineout"
     */

    if (!error && (route != NULL)) {

        NSString* routeStr = (__bridge NSString*)route;

        NSRange headphoneRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Head"];

        [self.cardSwipeDelegate headphoneListener:(headphoneRange.location != NSNotFound)];

        if (headphoneRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self startSession];
        } else {
            [self stopSession];
        }
    }
}
```

And where ever you do your initialization add the notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(_audioRouteChanged:) name:kAudioRouteChanged object:nil];
```